# Importing a module into a DSL job

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm writing a helper function for my Job-DSL Seed job, i.e., something like in `util/WebHook.groovy`:

```
package util
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

class WebHook {
  static void create() {
    def urls = new JsonSlurper().parseText(list_hooks.execute().text).url
[...]
```

then in `main.groovy`:

```
import util.WebHook
WebHook.create()
```

which seems to work fine. But if I try to use for instance a module from the Credentials Plugin, i.e.,

```
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider
```

I get an error:

> Processing DSL script terraform.groovy
>   ERROR: startup failed:
>   workspace:/util/WebHook.groovy: 5: unable to resolve class com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider
>   @ line 5, column 1.
>     import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider

Why is that? Is there a workaround, or should I use a different approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can not import classes from other plugins in Job DSL scripts.

But depending on what your trying to do, there are other ways to interact with classes from other plugins. `CredentialsProvider` is a `Descriptor`. You can use the `Jenkins` instance to lookup any descriptor instance:

```
Jenkins.instance.getExtensionList('com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider')
```